# bind9 does not answer to external requests on IONOS VPS

Tags: networking, dns, bind, bind9

I have a bind9 server running for requests for `i.example.com`. When I do a request from the nameserver to its own public IP like this `nslookup ns1.i.example.com xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` I get the expected answer:

```
Server:         xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Address:        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#53

Name:   ns1.i.example.com
Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

If I do the request from an office computer I do not get any answer:

```
C:\Users\user>nslookup ns1.i.example.com xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

Nmap shows me that port 53 is accessible from the office computer:

```
PORT   STATE         SERVICE
53/udp open|filtered domain
```

In my bind9 options I am also listening on my public IP address:

```
dnssec-validation auto;

listen-on-v6 { any; };
listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; };
allow-query {
        any;
};
allow-recursion { any; };
```

Also, I do not have any iptables rules set up.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: normally the firewall would block the DNS request, have you allowed it?

Comment: @SreeramNair I have a debian installation from my VPS provider. I am only familiar with iptables as a linux firewall. Any suggestions which firewall software I should look for? I have not installed any by my self.

Comment: This question is completely offtopic here as not related at all to programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My VPS provider IONOS has its extra firewall besides my iptables rules. Opnening port 53 in the administration panel did solve the problem.

Comment: Great That you found it. I was thinking there should be an extra firewall somewhere blocking it

Comment: @SreeramNair Yeah I felt a little bit like an idiot. But I never had any extra firewall with other VPS providers, so I did not consider it...